# How to determine row selected within jScrollPane

Tags: java

I am populating a jScrollPane (within a JFrame Swing GUI) with a list of files. Is there a way to determine which row the user has clicked on within jScrollPane. I want to identify the row and extract the contents of that row that the user selected.

Comment: Can you tell us how did you populate all files in jScrollPanel?

Comment: You might be better off using a JList or JTable which have built in selection functionality. Posting your existing code would make it easier to answer this question.

Comment: @219CID you answered by question. Using a JTable has proven to be way more powerful that a jScrollPane. Please mark this as an answer.

Comment: @macdays I've just added an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off using a JList or JTable which have built in selection functionality. Here is the [Oracle documentation on the basics of JTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

I suggest using [JTable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTable.html) with the [DefaultTableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) when you are first getting started.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can open a file or execute using a method called `process`

```
using System.Diagnostics;
Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo();
pi.UseShellExecute = true;
pi.FileName = @"MY_FILE_WITH_FULL_PATH.jpg";//c:\Desktop\example\sample.txt
p.StartInfo = pi;

try
{
    p.Start();
}
catch (Exception Ex)
{
    //MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);
}
```